# Updating data not working using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, updating

I am currently working on a project using codeigniter. As part of the project functionalities, it have edit or update function and I got some errors with it, its not working.Here are my codes as follows :

**Workers_model**

This the edit function or update .

```
   public function edit_workers_details ($worker_id, $data) {
            $this->db->where('worker_id', $worker_id);
            $this->db->update('worker_tb', $data);

            return $this->db->affected_rows();
        }

  public function get_worker_details ($worker_id) {
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('worker_tb');
    $this->db->where('worker_id', $worker_id);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}

**Workers (controller)**

public function edit_worker ($worker_id) {

        if ($_POST) {
            $worker_details = array (
                'worker_fname' => $_POST['worker_fname']


            );

            $this->Workers_model->edit_workers_details($worker_id, $worker_details);
            redirect("Workers/index");
        }

        $data['details'] = $this->Workers_model->get_worker_details($worker_id);
        $this->load->view('Worker/updateWorker',$data);
}
```

**updateWorker (view)**

```
<center>
    <h1> Edit Worker Details </h1>
    <?php foreach ($details as $detail) {?>
        <form role="form" action= "<?php echo site_url("Workers/edit_worker/".$detail['worker_id']);?>" method="POST">

            Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" class="form-control" value = "<?php echo $detail['worker_fname'];?>" ><br />

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Update </button>

        </form>

    <?php } ?>

</center>
```

My problem now is that when I click the Update button it's not working and does not update data.What should I do?
Any ideas or help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: instead of site_url try base_url in form but also have you looked at http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Your `<input>` field missing `name` attribute**

So **final well form code** is

**In View**

```
<center>
    <h1> Edit Worker Details </h1>
    <?php foreach ($details as $detail) {?>
        <form role="form" action= "<?php echo site_url("Workers/edit_worker/".$detail['worker_id']);?>" method="POST">

            Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="worker_fname" class="form-control" value = "<?php echo $detail['worker_fname'];?>" ><br />

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Update </button>

        </form>

    <?php } ?>

</center>
```

**In Controller**

```
public function edit_worker ($worker_id) {

    $worker_fname = $_POST['worker_fname'];

    if(!empty($worker_fname))
    {
        $result = $this->Workers_model->edit_workers_details($worker_id, $worker_fname);
        if($result == 1)
        {
            $data['details'] = $this->Workers_model->get_worker_details($worker_id);
            $this->load->view('Worker/updateWorker',$data); 
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Update Failed'
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'worker_fname is empty'
    }    

}
```

**In Model**

```
public function edit_workers_details ($worker_id, $worker_fname) {
    $data = array(
        'worker_fname' => $worker_fname
    );

    $this->db->where('worker_id', $worker_id);
    if(!$this->db->update('worker_tb', $data))
    {
        // Update Failed
        return $log = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // Update Success
        return $log = 1;
    }

}

public function get_worker_details ($worker_id) 
{
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('worker_tb');
    $this->db->where('worker_id', $worker_id);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use name attribute as "worker_fname"

```
Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name ="worker_fname"class="form-control" value = "<?php echo $detail['worker_fname'];?>" ><br />
```

then you can get value form value by from controller Like this

```
$this->input->post("worker_fname"); or $_POST['worker_fname']
```

then do what you want :D :D